# Solr: filtering using facet ranges with pivot

Tags: solr

I'm running a Solr query to get facets on a date field.  I have my range start set to 1/1/2019 and my end set to 4/1/2019.  The various gaps I'm using is +7 days, +1 month, +1 year.  In my example below are results when I use +7 days.

```
"facet_counts":{
  "facet_ranges":{
    "published_date":{
      "counts":[
        "2019-01-01T00:00:00Z",14,
        "2019-01-15T00:00:00Z",5,
        "2019-01-29T00:00:00Z",6,
        "2019-02-05T00:00:00Z",11,
        "2019-02-12T00:00:00Z",24,
        "2019-02-19T00:00:00Z",31,
        "2019-03-05T00:00:00Z",4,
        "2019-03-12T00:00:00Z",5,
        "2019-03-19T00:00:00Z",11,
        "2019-03-26T00:00:00Z",35],
      "gap":"+7DAYS",
      "start":"2019-01-01T00:00:00Z",
      "end":"2019-04-02T00:00:00Z"
    }
  }
}
```

I need the above facet information so I can categorize the documents I'm going to use for a graph in to those groups.  So the 14 documents for the range "2019-01-01T00:00:00Z" need to be displayed for that group and so on.  It will be those facets upon which the rest of my data will be represented.

Now I want to pivot on another field, available_inventory, because it will be used for the other part to be displayed for a range.
Here are my results for that pivot.

```
"facet_pivot":{
  "available_inventory":[{
      "field":"available_inventory",
      "value":"12",
      "count":64},
    {
      "field":"available_inventory",
      "value":"1",
      "count":57},
    {
      "field":"available_inventory",
      "value":"5",
      "count":57},
    {
      "field":"available_inventory",
      "value":"9",
      "count":56},
    {
      "field":"available_inventory",
      "value":"4",
      "count":52},
    {
      "field":"available_inventory",
      "value":"6",
      "count":52},
    {
      "field":"available_inventory",
      "value":"7",
      "count":51},
    {
      "field":"available_inventory",
      "value":"15",
      "count":50},
    {
      "field":"available_inventory",
      "value":"16",
      "count":50},
    {
      "field":"available_inventory",
      "value":"18",
      "count":50},
    {
      "field":"available_inventory",
      "value":"19",
      "count":50},
    {
      "field":"available_inventory",
      "value":"0",
      "count":49},
    {
      "field":"available_inventory",
      "value":"17",
      "count":49},
    {
      "field":"available_inventory",
      "value":"14",
      "count":48},
    {
      "field":"available_inventory",
      "value":"2",
      "count":48},
    {
      "field":"available_inventory",
      "value":"13",
      "count":47},
    {
      "field":"available_inventory",
      "value":"10",
      "count":46},
    {
      "field":"available_inventory",
      "value":"11",
      "count":43},
    {
      "field":"available_inventory",
      "value":"3",
      "count":43},
    {
      "field":"available_inventory",
      "value":"8",
      "count":36}]
    }
  }
}
```

So far so good.  But those counts are not representative of the ranges returned in the facet_ranges section.  Is there a way that I can get the two to mesh?  I've tried using facet.field instead of pivot.field but, again, there is no context (or even filtering) for what is coming back as part of the ranges.

Is it the case that for me to do anything with that facet_ranges data in terms of getting the docs matching that range (e.g., the 14 docs for "2019-01-01T00:00:00Z") I need to submit a subsequent query where published_date of a doc has the value for each of those ranges and then aggregate the available_inventory values.  If that is the case then is there any point in me trying to use additional facet.field arguments?  Or using those fields as pivots?  What I'm wondering is if there is a way to do this with a single query.  If there isn't a way how can I submit the query in such a way where all the docs for a particular range (e.g., "2019-01-01T00:00:00Z") is returned?  Given the fact that all I'm going to have access to after the fact is the start date?

I hope that I'm explaining myself well enough...

thnx,
Christoph

Comment: I'm not completely sure about your exact question, but you can [combine ranges and pivoting by using localparams](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/faceting.html#Faceting-CombiningFacetQueriesAndFacetRangesWithPivotFacets) with `{!range=tag}` and `{!tag=tag}`. Would that solve the issue?

Comment: Actually I think it will.  Thanks for the pointer!